# Select second word in between known phrases - R regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to **select text in between known phrases** but **exclude the first word** using R and regex. The format is as follows

```
"known phrase + unknown_word + target phrase + known_word + bla bla"
```

for example:

```
Tesco Plc sells coffee beans today in stores over the uk

Known phrase = "Tesco Plc"
Unknown word = "sells"
Target phrase = "coffee beans"
known word = "today"
bla bla (unrelated text) = "in stores over the uk"
```

**Initial Attempt**

```
text = "Tesco Plc sells coffee beans today in stores over the uk"
known_phrase = "Tesco Plc"
known_word = "today"

# code
str_extract(text, paste0("(?<=",known_phrase,").*(?=", known_word ,")"))]
```

This selects both the `unknown_word` and `target phrase`. But I just want the `target phrase`/

Comment: `stringr::str_match(x, "Tesco\\s+Plc\\s+\\w+\\s+(.*?)\\s+today")[,2]`? See https://regex101.com/r/oztc5i/1. `str_extract` is not that flexible when your context is not static.

Comment: that worked better combined with `str_remove`, many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
stringr::str_match(x, "Tesco\\s+Plc\\s+\\w+\\s+(.*?)\\s+today")[,2]
## OR
Known_phrase = "Tesco Plc"
known_word = "today"
stringr::str_match(x, paste0(Known_phrase, "\\s+\\w+\\s+(.*?)\\s+", known_word))[,2]
```

You might need an escaping function since your variables are dynamic:

```r
regex.escape <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^$|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}
Known_phrase = "Tesco Plc"
known_word = "today"
stringr::str_match(x, paste0(regex.escape(Known_phrase), "\\s+\\w+\\s+(.*?)\\s+", regex.escape(known_word)))[,2]
```